# Change PHP current directory

Tags: php

Script file name:

```
c:\wtserver\www\testclass\index.php
http://localhost = c:\wtserver\www\
```

The code:

```
<?php
        print getcwd()."<br/>";
        chdir(dirname(__FILE__).'\product\\');
        print getcwd()."<br/>";
        print '<img src="img/1.jpg"/>';
?>
```

The output is:

```
c:\wtserver\www\testclass
C:\WTServer\WWW\testclass\product
```

and the image location is:

```
http://localhost/testclass/img/1.jpg
```

What I need is that image location should be:

```
http://localhost/testclass/product/img/1.jpg
```

Without changing this line:

```
print '<img src="img/1.jpg"/>';
```

Thanks.

Comment: why you don't want to change that line? the relative path in `src` has to do nothing with php, but with the html parsing client: the client attempts to make a get request relative to the location of the containing document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `print '<img src="img/1.jpg"/>';` with print `'<img src="product/img/1.jpg"/>';`

There is no correlation between `chdir` and building urls. `chdir` command has an affect only on folders of the filesystem of your server/local computer and it's doesn't participate in forming urls for your page.

Comment: Also perhaps recommend `<base href="/img">`, if he wants that globally

Comment: Thanks @bwoebi, that's what I need. Sorry I'm new to html and php.